# How to check what files I have opened but only in active dir

Tags: perforce

I'd like to see what files I have checked out but only in my active dir.

If I try:

> `p4 opened *.*`

it works but I also get a lot of unwanted information.  A bunch of 
"<foo> - file(s) not opened on this client".

I tried piping the command to grep so I can filter these out but it seems grep has no effect.  Maybe this is getting piped to stderr?

Is there a clean way to see what files I have checked out in the current dir?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, those "not opened on this client" messages were going to stderr (since they are error messages), rather than stdout. You could of course redirect stderr into stdout by doing `2 >&1` at the end of your command, but Sam's answer below is much nicer.

Answer (score 4):

Do:

```
p4 opened ...
```

The `...` wildcard spans subdirectories; if you only want files at the top level of the current directory, and don't want your shell to expand it, do:

```
p4 opened "*"
```

This may vary by shell -- I think the Windows shell doesn't require any quoting at all in this situation, but double quotes are required for most Unix-y shells.  Since `...` is a Perforce-specific wildcard it generally doesn't need quoting.